# wp7 app + skydrive, trouble with viewing a file

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

Im able to authenticate and able to get file's direct url.
And it looks like this: https://skydrive.live.com/MobileProtocol?ptcl=office%3a&dav=https%3a%2f%2fd.docs.live.net%2f9808b4a6c33c1bc4%2ffirst.xlsx

Iam able to open this file using WebBrowserTask but not with built-in phone:WebBrowser control. The problem with WebBrowserTask is, this opens outside my app and cannot be used for secure documents.

Any suggestions?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, this is the only way to open documents using WP7. You cannot get around this limitation using the current SDK. Perhaps Windows Phone 7.8 or WP8 might be better.